# Jsp displaying no output

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have following code in my jsp and there is not other code in it

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setStatus(204);

    // then write the response
    out.println("Receipt");
```

Now when I call this jsp from my browser, it does not display "Receipt".
What can be the reason ? Am I sending response of 204 to my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status 204 means NO CONTENT.  From the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) :

> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

That means the webserver is not going to send anything you print.